# Strange phase portrait

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, vector-fields

Could you comment on what has been the two-dimensional differential equation (with field of vectors of class $C^1$) whose phase portrait is strange or unusual?

For example in [this article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0893965917300083?via%3Dihub) I found the following:
\begin{align}
\dot{r}&=-(r-1)^5\\
\dot{\theta}&=\left\{
\begin{array}{lcc}
0&,&r=1\\
-(r-1)^3\sin\left(\dfrac{3}{2(r-1)}\right)&,&r\ne 1
\end{array}
\right.
\end{align}
whose phase portrait is:
[image]

When I think of something strange, many things come to mind, such as:

[image]

Comment: In "an article"?   Ummm.... *which* article?  And please define "strange," not merely give an example.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork By "strange" I mean not an example that can be found in any book. This is a pretty broad question where I would like to see several answers with interesting two-dimensional ODE's that are not common.